# Converte dates in excell to text vith vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want my code to do something like this, but I cant figure out the right code

```
Sub InsertDateAsFormulaASText()

Dim WSD As Worksheet
Set WSD = Worksheets("TEST")

FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' Run trough all rows and set values in coloumn A

    For i = 2 To FinalRow

        ' If value in column 3 are = "Intern Audit" then
        If Cells(i, 3) = "Intern Audit" Then
            ' Insert in column 4 the date from Column 1 as text
            Cells(i, 4).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=TEXT(RC[-3],"åååå") ' This is the part that failed

        Else
            ' Insert in column 4 the date from Column 2 as text
            Cells(i, 4).Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1=TEXT(RC[-2],"åååå") ' This is the part that failed
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It should be: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-3],""åååå"")"`

Comment: Great it works, Thank you very much, I have fought with that code for days :)